# Web Api 2.2 set cookie for parent domain

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cookies

Hello I am tearing what little hair I have left out!

I need to emit a cookie from Web API 2.2 but the emitted cookie is always set at the subdomain not parent domain level.
I have tried  cookie.Domain = ".parent.com"; the cookie is always subdomain.parent.com and therefore unreadable by other subdomains.

```
var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session-id", "12345");
cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
cookie.Domain = "parent.com";
cookie.Path = "/";

response.Result.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
```

Comment: Found the problem. I am also using ARR and had reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders selected.

Answer (score 0):

Application Request Routing (ARR) is also being used and Reverse rewrite host in response headers was selected in the ARR proxy settings.